Jitsi Changing Default Virtual Background
I connect to my container and replace one of the default backgrounds in /usr/share/jitsi-meet/images/virtual-background with my own background.I make the names the same i.e. background-6.jpg.But the replaced background is black and cannot be clicked.As in the following picture

Can anyone help me why I'm getting this error or how do I add my own background permanently?
